# Why use Puma if we already have HTTP servers such as Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, nginx, rack, puma

Why is it commonplace to use the next architecture?

```
Client (e.g: browser) --> Nginx --> Puma --> Rails App
```

I think that we can go without using Puma at all since it's also an HTTP server as Nginx with less capabilities.

Having Puma in the middle, is having a second HTTP server, and we already have Nginx that handles HTTP requests.

The only thing that Nginx would lack instead is a Rack interface to communicate with Rails, but that just a matter of implementing an Rack adapter for it.

So instead we can have this and eliminate redundancy:

```
Client (e.g: browser) --> Nginx --> Rails App
```

Basically what am I missing here? Puma knows how to handle various Rails processes? If so, then Nginx can create several worker_processes also.

Comment: You may be underestimating the complexity of "just a matter of implementing a Rack adapter" (see phusion passenger for example)

Comment: I couldn't even underestimate it, because to begin with, I was not even able to discern their roles so I was not sure what roles each component fulfilled.

Now I do and it makes sense (refer to my "edit" part of my question) for more info